# Can entire long articles be tagged as Schema.org articleBody, or is there a word count limit?

Tags: schema.org, articles

I have long articles on my website, so I was wondering if there are any limits on word count for [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody) while implementing Schema.org.

Should I tag the whole text as `articleBody` or just a brief?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema.org** sets no limits like that. It’s your text, it’s as long as it is. If you use [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody), you should provide the full text. Otherwise you misuse this property, as it’s defined to hold the body of the article, not just a part of the body. For a teaser/summary/abstract, use [`description`](http://schema.org/description) instead.

**Consumers** might of course have technical limits when working with `articleBody`.

In case of the consumer **Google Search**: their [Article rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article) doesn’t seem to make use of `articleBody` at all, so they have no need to declare a possible length limit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Word Count limit as the viewpoint of Schema.org.

But According to Google and Experts, Your Content Must be Upto 10000 words.

But no limit of wordcount in schema markup. you can write your content long as much you need.